# Second input box in form doesn't work second time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, form-submit

I have this form:

```
<form id="addChore" method="post" action="allocate.php">

  <label>Name of new chore:</label>
  <input type="text" id = "choreName" name="choreName">
  <p></p>

  <label>Description:</label>
  <input type="text" id="description" name="description">
  <p></p>

  <label>Frequency:</label>
  <select id="frequency" name="frequency">
...
  </select>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and this jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#addChore").on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#error").empty();
        var name = $("#choreName").val();
        console.log(name);

        var description = $("#description").val();
        console.log(description);

        var frequency = $("#frequency").val();
        console.log(frequency);

        var message=("Please fill all fields");
        // $('#addChore')[0].reset();

        if (!name || !description){
            $("#error").append("<p>"+message+"</p>");
            return false;
        }
        else{...}
```

but when I try and use the form a second time, description is empty in the log, while name and frequency accept a new input. I have tried resets and .val("") but nothing seems to change this. Any help? :/

Comment: Any duplicated id attribute for the "description"?

Comment: I am getting value correctly. do you have multiple element with same id of description?

Comment: No, this is the only element with that id. That's why I am confused

Comment: @Dhara by correct do you mean it shows up with a value?

Comment: yes with the value

Comment: I have solved it! I changed the name of the id and it works now. It is a bit odd but I imagine that it has been interfering with some php scripts I had before my html. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had another element with the same id, but defined in php in a separate script